# Running `npm install` in git submodule before deploy finishes in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, node.js, elastic-beanstalk

My Node.js project has some git submodules (this is something that cannot be easily changed right now, so I can't use a package registry like npm)

While EB will automatically init and update the submodules, I need to run `npm install` in each one of them in order to make them work properly.

What is the recommended way of doing so?

I've read something about just adding a `prestart` script in my `package.json`, like:

```
"prestart" : "git submodule foreach npm install"
```

But this doesn't feel right.

I already have some scripts in `.ebextensions`, but I'm not sure in which point I should put such script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer with the help of the folks at AWS support.

I added a file named `00custom_npm.config` in my `.ebextensions` with the following:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/51_submodules_install_dependencies.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash
      EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir)
      cd $EB_APP_STAGING_DIR/<submodule-name> && /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.3.0-linux-x64/bin/npm install
```

I need to do it manually for each of the modules. In my case, since it's just one, it's easy.